# Работают ли регулярные выражения в re.sub(), line.split() Python 2.7

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-2.x

Ищу в строке подстроку и удаляю ее, с регулярками не работает.

Файл содержит строки:

```
Vendor  : Intel 
Version : update 2
```

Код:

```
file = open(o,"r")
line = file.readline()
lines = line.split(" ")
venstr = "*.Vendor\s*:"
verstr = "*.Version\s*:"#regular
for p in lines:
    if ("*.Vendor\s*:" in p):
        p1 = re.sub(venstr, "", p)
        print p.strip()
    elif ("*.Version\s*:" in p):
        p2 = re.sub(verstr, "", p)
        print p2.strip()
    else: continue
```

Comment: сразу простите за кривую вставку кода(

Comment: А вставить нормально - не судьба?

Comment: @Qwertiy провтыкал немного(

Comment: Слеши нужно экранировать `"*.Vendor\s*:"` -> `"*.Vendor\\s*:"`. А так в коде проглядывают сишные корни (if в питоне без скобок пишется, continue в цикле лишний (или это не все тело цикла)). Кроме того ошибка копипасты в виде переменных `venstr `. А в одном условии удаляется `"verstr"`, хотя там ожидается переменная. Еще я уверен что в строках файла нет строк `*.Vendor\s*:`, а они все же ищутся. Если по шаблону поиск нужен, используйте `re.search` или `re.match`

Comment: @gil9red  - в файле есть строка "Vendor  : " я пытаюсь найти ее и все, что идет до нее в месте с ней удалить

Comment: Смотрите, ваш текущий код не работает и чтобы его протестировать желающим нужно поднапрячься, возьмите несколько строк из файла, сохраните в переменную, разбейте строку через `split` или `splitlines` и получите `lines`. Т.е. в вашем вопросе нехватает: данных на которых код натравляете и что тот код должен был сделать

Comment: Не пробовали, кст, на python3 перейти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import re

f = open('file', mode='r')

vendor_pattern = ".*Vendor\\s*:"
version_pattern = ".*Version\\s*:"

for line in f:
    if re.search(vendor_pattern, line):
        p1 = re.sub(vendor_pattern, '', line)
        print p1.strip()

    elif re.search(version_pattern, line):
        p2 = re.sub(version_pattern, '', line)
        print p2.strip()

f.close()
```

В консоле:

```
Intel
update 2
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.

Comment: @Denis, хорошо, а то я писал на python 3.5 и боялся где-то накосячить при приведении кода к python 2 ))